# How to extract a word which is having an extension from a string using regex?

Tags: c#, regex, string

I need to extract a word from a string before an extension. Let's say I've got a string like :

`"Hey Stackoverflow.xyz Whats up?"`

I need to extract a word with extension .xyz i.e Stackoverflow. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use positive look ahead to ensure the string you want to extract follows `.xyz` using this regex,

```
\S+(?=\.xyz)
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/RzbigR/1)**

Try these C# codes,

```
string str = "Hey Stackoverflow.xyz Whats up?";
var m = Regex.Match(str,@"\S+(?=\.xyz)");
Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[0].Value);
```

Outputs,

```
Stackoverflow
```

**[Online C# demo](https://rextester.com/SFNQD9867)**

In case you want to extract your string with extension `Stackoverflow.xyz`, just change the look ahead part of regex to normal string like this,

```
\S+\.xyz
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/(\w+)\\.[^\W]+/
```

[Play with it at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/W9y1r0/1)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following regex to extract the word you need before the extension

```
\s(.*)?\.
```

Here the word will be captured using the brackets.

```
string str = "Hey Stackoverflow.xyz Whats up?";
var regexResult = Regex.Match(str,@"\s(.*)?\.");
Console.WriteLine(regexResult.Groups[1].Value);
```